# Data race in C++

Tags: c++11, x86

```
struct S {
int a;
int b;
};
```

Size of L1 cache line is equal 64B.

```
global S s;
Thread1:
s.a = 2;

Thread2: 
s.b = 1;
```

Is it a data race in C++?

Answer (score 3):

No it is not a data race. `s.a` and `s.b` are different memory locations . They are accessed and modified independently of each other.

> **[intro.memory]/3** A *memory location* is either an object of scalar type or a maximal sequence of adjacent bit-fields all having non-zero width. [ *Note:* Various features of the language, such as references and virtual functions, might involve additional memory locations that are not accessible to programs but are managed by the implementation. — *end note* ] Two or more threads of execution (1.10) can update and access separate memory locations without interfering with each other.

Comment: Yes, but please note that CPU doesn't see: memory address as one byte. It sees cache line.

Comment: That's not your problem, but the C++ compiler's and/or CPU's. The compiled program must behave as if `s.a` and `s.b` were separate and independent, or else the compiler is non-conforming (aka buggy). You asked whether your example exhibits a data race according to the C++ language rules: it does not. Hardware implementation details are irrelevant to this question.

Comment: So, do you mean that according to the definition, `s.a` is an object of scalar type?

Comment: Yes of course. "**[basic.types]/9** Arithmetic types (3.9.1), enumeration types, pointer types, pointer to member types (3.9.2), std::nullptr_-
t, and cv-qualified versions of these types (3.9.3) are collectively called *scalar types*." `int` would be an arithmetic type.

Comment: @J.Doe You may be interested in the MESI protocol and variants, they are used to keep the cache coherent among processors (in the IA32e family).

Comment: @J.Doe: More specifically, using s.a and s.b independently in different threads is a textbook example of "false sharing", leading to the cache line holding them both ping-ponging from one core to another.  This is extremely bad for performance, but doesn't present any correctness problems.